# How to make a newfile-function opening the new file in a new frame?

Tags: org-mode

I use Emacs org-mode for note taking during philosophical dialogs. I make one new file for each idea encountered, using this code:

```
(defun myfun-create-note-file()
  "Doc-string."
  (interactive)
  (find-file (format-time-string "C:/Users/myUser/notes/%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S.txt"))
  (insert "*note :tags: \n\n")                        

(global-set-key "\C-cn" ' myfun-create-note-file)
```

However, when making several new files during one session, only the last one is visible in the Emacs frame. The rest of the files reside within the Emacs instance, and have to be visited by cycling through the open buffer list.

I would like to open every new file in a separate frame, of small size. How can I modify my code to do this?

Comment: `C-h f find-file-other-frame` and refs therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find-file-other-frame` instead of `find-file`:

```
find-file-other-frame is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`files.el'.

(find-file-other-frame FILENAME &optional WILDCARDS)

Edit file FILENAME, in another frame.

Like M-x find-file (which see), but creates a new frame or reuses
an existing one.  See the function ‘display-buffer’.

Interactively, the default if you just type RET is the current directory,
but the visited file name is available through the minibuffer history:
type M-n to pull it into the minibuffer.

Interactively, or if WILDCARDS is non-nil in a call from Lisp,
expand wildcards (if any) and visit multiple files.
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it :)

Answer (score 1):

You say, *"I would like to open every new file in a separate frame, of small size."*

1. To *always* use a separate frame, by default, set option `pop-up-frames` to `t`.
2. To get frames that fit the buffer content (narrow, for narrow buffer lines, short, for short buffers), use libraries [`fit-frame.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/fit-frame.el) and [`auto-fit-frame.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/autofit-frame.el). See [Shrink-Wrapping Frames](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Shrink-Wrapping_Frames).

---

If you instead want to always use the *same* size frame (instead of having the frame fit the buffer content) then customize option `special-display-regexps` to a value that matches *all* buffer names, and then customize option `special-display-frame-alist` to have the size etc. you want.

Comment: Thanks for valuable info! I will test it out.